# Ajax request failed because file not found error, but works in address bar directly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

In `code-igniter 3.0`, i am using ajax request for deleting a file from data-table, but in console i am getting error that the URL being passed in Ajax request is not found but amazingly the record gets deleted. I found a solution to use `dataType:jsonp` that worked but i cannot make changes in my application there are too many ajax requests. Problem occured after shifting my project from `XAMPP` to hosting server. Can any one help me.
Ajax request is like:

```
function deleteBlog(id){
        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo base_url()."Static_pages/deleteBlogContent/"?>'+id,
            type:'POST',
            success: function(data){
                my_table.ajax.reload( null, false);
            }
        })
    }
```

Another issue that i faced is that when i use this url :

```
url:'<?php echo base_url()."index.php/Static_pages/deleteBlogContent/"?>'+id,
```

rather than this:

```
url:'<?php echo base_url()."Static_pages/deleteBlogContent/"?>'+id,
```

it works. 
I also noticed in Network tab that the origin: is different from host and referer.

Comment: The fact you can only access the Controller/method using index.php in the url, indicates you might have a missing .htaccess file. Did you upload it? Also check your $config['base_url'] etc are correct on the hosted site.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have htaccess uploaded on server also the base url is correct. The main thing is that the same url works on address bar while gives error on ajax request. I doubt that the htaccess is restricted by new server, I tried writing a random text in htaccess in very start and it gave me error when accessing the website, it means htaccess is accessible by server. If i upload htaccess can any one tell me what is wrong ?